# Have a select form field get today's day of the week

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I have a form where you can select a day of the week to search the corresponding data. I would like to have some way of having todays day of the week preselected when the form loads. Any guidance would be appreciated, i assume this would be javascript,which I know very little.
Joe

```html
<select name="tax_days" id="days-tax" class="gmw-dropdown-days gmw-dropdown-taxonomy">
 <option value="0"> – All – </option>
 <option class="level-0" value="15">Monday</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="29">Tuesday</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="5">Wednesday</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="43">Thursday</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="54">Friday</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="57">Saturday</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="65">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var currentDay = new Date().getDay();
    if (currentDay == 0) {
      // Sunday is at the end of the select
      currentDay = 7;
    }
    document.getElementById("days-tax").selectedIndex = currentDay;
};
```

```html
<select name="tax_days" id="days-tax" class="gmw-dropdown-days gmw-dropdown-taxonomy">
  <option value="0">– All –</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="15">Monday</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="29">Tuesday</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="5">Wednesday</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="43">Thursday</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="54">Friday</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="57">Saturday</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="65">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked beautifully. You really saved me hours of trying, although I should be practicing/learning js on my own, lol. Thanks again really appreciated, Barmar!